# Create multiple eventListeners to one specific element

Tags: javascript

I want to create an click and a touch start event here is my code:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click",function(event: any) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(self.overlayView, "click");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

How do I create an simple implementation for this without doing this:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "touchstart",function(event: any) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(self.overlayView, "click");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export function to a named function and bind same function to both event.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/yo0kazbc/1/)

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('tile')[0].addEventListener('click', handler)
document.getElementsByClassName('tile')[0].addEventListener('mousedown', handler)

function handler(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```